# Two stems coming from my hass avocado graft. A bit concerning

Tags: avocado, grafting

I just recieved my hass avocado tree from fast growing trees and I'm a little concerned about my graft. Theres a secondary growth coming out of the graft point and this one ends up being longer and healthier than the main one. In the first picture I show the grafting point. The growth on the left actually is the one that ends up the tallest. The thicker one on the right curls behind the other, and ends up dying at about 1ft. It seems to me that I should prune the thicker one but it appears that its the intended graph (pic 3). The other longer one looks like part of the rootstock. Should I prune one of these or just leave it alone?

[image]

[image]

My images are too big to upload here. Ive got one more picture on my reddit post.

https://reddit.com/r/gardening/s/22rqY0Zf9H

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's very likely that the vigorous growth from the graft point is really from the rootstock (a sucker) and should be removed. It's normal for rootstock suckers to be more vigorous than grafted tops (in other trees, I have no particular experience with avocado specifically.)

If this is the way it "just arrived" from the vendor, you should definitely ask your vendor.

Comment: The plant must have shipped better with the mother, but she now gotta go. Angle cut just above the graft.

Answer (score 1):

As @Ecneral post - the vigorous growth is from the rootstock - this is likely not going to give you the avocado you want (In my country Rootstock are typically propriety or "Zutano" - which is apparently not a great eating avocado.

Conventional wisdom would be to cut off the lower branch (ie the left one in the picture) - but I'd reach out to the vendor - that plant does not look healthy to me.    Note the brown bit on the main trunk - if you are not able to return the plant from whence you bought it, you should cut it off just above a node where it is still green

Unfortunately the plant looks a little sick - and I'm not sure its going to "make it".  Good luck - I genuinely hope it does.

Comment: It just occured to me - if this is an indoor/ornmental plant, it likely does not matter if its Hass or something else - if you don't need it for the fruit, cut off the right hand side above the graft and just enjoy the foliage from the healthy rootstock.